# Is it possible to use an Azure Web Job to listen on a public socket

Tags: sockets, azure, web, azure-webjobs, hl7

Can an Azure Web Job listen on a public TCP port (socket)

I am deploying a Web Application to Azure, and it has a long running Web Job that listens to a TCP port (a custom protocol is involved, so a raw socket is required)

The listener runs, but I want to send data from outside of Azure, from another on-prem machine.

The port is listening OK, it can open an incoming socket, but it is internal (10.0.X.X)

I suspect a public port like this is NOT possible, but I want to be 100% sure of that limitation, before I invest in an alternate solution.

FWIW, the protocol is for HL7

If it is not possible, would a point to point VPN into the Web Application be one option, to tunnel the connection from on-prem to the Web App?

Are there other approaches (maybe Azure Functions) that I should consider instead?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you will not be able to listen on a public socket. See [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#networking-restrictionsconsiderations) for more details about the App Service sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it but doesn't work!
See the limitations:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening

But I could create a client application that can listen a non-http port.
Also, It is possible to host the TCPListener app in ServiceFabric. I could host my existing application (WCF Console host) as a GuestExecutable in ServiceFabric without any code changes. I would recommend to go for ServiceFabric..its scalable and very reliable service.